# Finding Start and End date of a sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

So I basically have a table with one entry per day, per room. I need to find the start and end date of all sequential days grouped on that room, property, and notes.

```
property     room   date        notes
----------------------------------------------
2            101    2013-01-01  abc
2            101    2013-01-02  abc
2            101    2013-01-03  abc
2            101    2013-01-04  abc
2            101    2013-01-05  xyz
2            101    2013-01-06  xyz
2            101    2013-01-15  abc
2            101    2013-01-16  abc
2            101    2013-01-17  abc
2            107    2013-01-02  def
2            107    2013-01-03  def
2            109    2013-01-01  abc
2            109    2013-01-02  abc
3            101    2012-12-31  abc
3            101    2013-01-01  abc
3            101    2013-01-02  abc
```

I need to be able to query it based on property and date pretty much. When I search by date I should be able to use a date after the "start date" of the sequence and still find the proper start date. So if i search for say WHERE date = '2013-01-02' I should return something like :

```
property   room   start_date      end_date    notes
----------------------------------------------------
2          101    2013-01-01      2013-01-04  abc
2          107    2013-01-02      2013-01-03  def
2          109    2013-01-01      2013-01-02  abc
3          101    2012-12-31      2013-01-02  abc
```

This will be used with a fairly large table and return hundreds of thousands of results, so efficiency is a primary concern. I've found and tried to apply some examples all with issue. Most were too unbearably slow, or wouldn't return the correct start date if it was before the WHERE date clause, etc.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Analysis of large "ad hoc" datasets is not really MySQL's primary strength and I suspect you won't easily get the performance you desire. There's nothing else in the tables that may help, like a unique booking id?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the data you want can be obtained using `group by`:

```
select property, room, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date, notes
from table t
group by property, room, notes;
```

To get the rows for a particular date, using a `having` clause:

```
select property, room, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date, notes
from table t
group by property, room, notes
having date( '2013-01-02') between min(date) and max(date);
```

I'm not sure if there is another method that would be more efficient, although this does require aggregation on the entire table.

Comment: Hm, I suspect that the data set is not really representative of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of large datasets is not really MySQL's strength, so I suspect you'll have a hard time getting great performance. This query would seem to solve the problem at hand, but is not necessarily the fastest;

```sql
SELECT r.property, r.room, 
       MAX(IF(rr.date<=r.date AND is_start, rr.date, NULL)) start_date, 
       MIN(IF(rr.date>=r.date AND is_end,   rr.date, NULL)) end_date, 
       r.notes
FROM rooms r
JOIN (SELECT r.*, IF(ry.room IS NULL, 1, 0) is_start,
                  IF(rt.room IS NULL, 1, 0) is_end
      FROM (SELECT *, DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) yesterday,
                      DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) tomorrow FROM rooms) r
      LEFT JOIN rooms ry 
        ON r.property=ry.property AND r.room=ry.room AND r.notes=ry.notes
       AND r.yesterday=ry.date
      LEFT JOIN rooms rt
        ON r.property=rt.property AND r.room=rt.room AND r.notes=rt.notes
       AND r.tomorrow=rt.date
      WHERE ry.room IS NULL OR rt.room IS NULL) rr
  ON r.property = rr.property AND r.room = rr.room AND r.notes = rr.notes
WHERE r.date = '2013-01-02'
GROUP BY r.property, r.room, r.notes
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d531c/1). Note the indexes in the Fiddle which should speed things up.